# Dynamically build a variable and use it in a query in a plpgsql function

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, plpgsql

I have a function in a Postgres 9.6 DB where I want to dynamically set the month to be cumulative based on the input received.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(
    IN p_fiscal_year integer,
    IN p_month text,
    IN pid integer,
    IN fid integer)   RETURNS TABLE(col1 text , col2 text, col3 text, col4 text, col5 text)

AS $BODY$
DECLARE user_sel_month TEXT;
BEGIN

 CASE WHEN p_month ='October' Then 'October'         WHEN p_month = 'November' Then '(' ||'October' || ',' || 'November' || ')'     END;
 RETURN QUERY select 
                col1,
                col2,
                col3,
                col4,
                col5 
                from testtable 
                WHERE testtable.year = p_fiscal_year  
                AND trim(testtable.month) IN (user_sel_month) 
                AND testtable.pgmid = pid 
                and testtable.fun_id = fid )
```

But I am unable to do it in a Postgres function.
It returns no data when passed 'November', I do get data for 'October'.

```
select * from test(2016,'November',11,6);
```

I want to build the variable dynamically to make it cumulative so when 'November' is passed I want the query to use:

```
WHERE trim(testtable.month) IN ('October','November')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need dynamic variable here - use plain SQL instead - will be cheaper.

try to change:

```
AND trim(testtable.month) IN (user_sel_month)
```

to simple:

```
AND CASE 
  WHEN p_month = 'October' Then trim(testtable.month) in ('October')         
  WHEN p_month = 'November' Then trim(testtable.month) in ('October','November') 
END
```

Comment: Thank you Vao Tsun... this helped..  simple thinking helps

Answer (score 0):

If the only allowed input for `p_month` is 'October' or 'November', you can simplify further:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 
FROM   testtable
WHERE  year = p_fiscal_year  
AND   (trim(month) = 'October'
    OR trim(month) = 'November' AND p_month = 'November')
AND    pgmid = pid 
AND    fun_id = fid;
```

But that's an odd use case. And it's just putting lipstick on a pig to begin with.

Don't save `year` and `month` as `integer` and `text` in `testtable`. Use a single `date` column (4 bytes) for the month instead. (Smaller faster, cleaner.) The day component of the date is irrelevant in your case. Just allow any day and ignore it or enforce dates with day '1' in the table:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable (
   fiscal_month date NOT NULL CHECK (EXTRACT('day' FROM fiscal_month) = 1)
   --  more columns
);
```

The added `CHECK` constraint is optional.
To *see* data like before, add a [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html):

```
CREATE VIEW test_table_pretty AS 
SELECT EXTRACT('year' FROM fiscal_month)::int AS year
     , to_char(fiscal_month, 'Month')         AS month
       --  more columns
FROM   testtable;
```

Your function is simple and fast now:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(
    p_fiscal_year integer,
    p_month integer,           -- integer!
    pid integer,
    fid integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(col1 text, col2 text, col3 text, col4 text, col5 text) AS
$func$
   SELECT t.col1, t.col2, t.col3, t.col4, t.col5 
   FROM   testtable t 
   WHERE  fiscal_month >= make_date(p_fiscal_year, 10         , 1)  -- hard coded Oct.
   AND    fiscal_month <  make_date(p_fiscal_year, p_month + 1, 1)
   AND    t.pgmid  = pid 
   AND    t.fun_id = fid;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

This is *actually* cumulative, in the sense that you can pass any month later than October (only December left in your example).

Use [`make_date()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) (Postgres 9.4 or later) to conveniently build a date from `integer` input.